# break bash: parse_git_branch: command not found

Tags: bash, git-bash

Installed zsh and later on I try to uninstall but it was not installing so I deleted the folders/files manually and after that I started seeing the issues, so everytime I type command in the terminal I see `bash: parse_git_branch: command not found`

I check it shows that I have default shell is `bash` (going to system pref->users-)

What do I need to do to bring back the bash? looks like I screwed up the shell, is that possible if I can uninstall and install fresh bash?

I did brew uninstall bash or brew install bash

I get this message:

brew uninstall bash

```
Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.
bash: parse_git_branch: command not found
```

I try to change ownership to the current logged in user by using this command: after executing the below command I get `bash: parse_git_branch: command not found`

```
sudo chown $USER /usr/local/bin/brew
```

this is how my `.bash_profile` looks like

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/' }

export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w - \$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon/line break before the closing brace. Is that a typo?

Comment: Beyond what oguz ismail said, which is itself important: You shouldn't export your `PS1`. Doing so causes subprocesses to inherit it, _but they won't inherit the function_, so they get the `PS1` value but not the function that it requires at evaluation time.

Comment: You can use `export -f parse_git_branch` to export the `parse_git_bash` function, but even then, that exports it in a format that only the same shell is going to be guaranteed to parse and import correctly; it's safer to export neither, and instead require them both to be defined via `~/.bashrc` or local equivalent (Apple breaks convention when they use `.bash_profile` for all new terminal windows; per standard convention it _should_ be used only for login shells -- that is, the first shell in a session, for which all other shells are child processes).

Comment: Anyhow -- if you want to see if the function is declared in your current shell, you can run `declare -f parse_git_branch`. If it's declared, that'll print its text; if not, it'll show an error. It may not be declared because the syntax was bad (because you were missing a semicolon or newline before the `}`), or it may not be declared because you're in a child process that it wasn't exported to, but end result is the same.

Comment: Also, for interactive environment configuration questions, consider our sister site [unix.se]. This isn't particularly programming-related: The _particular_ function you're trying to call interacts with git, but the problem could occur with _any_ function used from a prompt, including ones that aren't development-related at all.

Comment: I just open the `.bash_profile` I haven't change the file, so I'm little lost so what do I need to do to fix the problem, I'm not an expert iin the bash field, can you please guide me?

Comment: Are you sure that this file has been sourced? What happens if you source it manually?

Comment: Source it manually? What does it mean

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the `bash: parse_git_branch: command not found` error by editing your `~/.bash_profile` file and adding the missing semi-colon:

```sh
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'; }
```

Alternatively, you could put the `}` on a newline:

```sh
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
```

After you have saved your edits, then you can source your `~/.bash_profile` by running

```sh
. ~/.bash_profile
```

After you have sourced your `~/.bash_profile`, you can confirm the function was sourced properly by running

```sh
type parse_git_branch
```

This should show the function if it was sourced correctly, or display an error if it was not sourced correctly.